# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm starting in Python, I'm making a Discord bot few weeks, nowdays, when I was trying to make a "Poll System" in my bot, I had an error like this:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'
```

My code:

```
    @client.command()
async def hlasovani(self, ctx, volba1, volba2, *, tema):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = tema,description = f":one: {volba1}\n\n:two: {volba2}",color = ctx.author.color,timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    embed.set_footer(text = f"Hlasování zahájil {ctx.author.name}")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
    message = await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    await message.add_reaction("1️⃣")
    await message.add_reaction("2️⃣")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    newmessage = await ctx.fetch_message(message.id)
    onechoice = await newmessage.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    secchoice = await newmessage.reactions[1].users().flatten()

    vysledek = "REMÍZA!"
    if len(onechoice)>len(secchoice):
        vysledek = volba1
    elif len(secchoice)<len(onechoice):
        vysledek = volba2

    embed = discord.Embed(title = tema, description = f"Výsledek: {vysledek}", color = ctx.author.color, timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    embed.set_footer(text = f"{volba1} || {volba2}")

    await newmessage.edit(embed = embed)
```

I will be really thankful for any kind of help...

Comment: and what line does this error occur in, show full traceback (edit the post to include it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `@client.command()` instead of `@commands.command()`, I would assume your command is not in a cog or another class.  If that's the case, you need to remove the `self` argument from your command.

```py
async def hlasovani(ctx, volba1, volba2, *, tema):
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!